# SELECTING DISTINCT Records

Tags: sql

My question is LAME. I KNOW! But I cannot figure it out, yet! Here is what I want to do: 
I have a set of records which is duplicate at 'JobNumber' and 'JobID'. Here is my query that is selecting the records:

```
SELECT  dbo.InvoiceLineDetail.JobNumber,
    dbo.InvoiceLineDetail.PatientName,
    dbo.InvoiceLineDetail.CustomerAccountName AS Name,
    COALESCE(InvoiceLineDetail.ShipAddressAddr2 + ' ',
        '') + COALESCE(InvoiceLineDetail.ShipAddressAddr3+' ',
        '') + COALESCE(InvoiceLineDetail.ShipAddressAddr4 +' ',
        '') + coalesce(InvoiceLineDetail.ShipAddressCity +' ',
        '') + COALESCE(InvoiceLineDetail.ShipAddressState +' ',
        '') + COALESCE(InvoiceLineDetail.ShipAddressCountry,
        '') as [Address],
     dbo.InvoiceLineDetail.ShipAddressPostalCode AS ZipCode,
     dbo.JobStatus.JobTableId AS JobID,
     dbo.JobStatus.OrderType,
     dbo.JobStatus.ShipTrackingNumber as Tracking#,
     dbo.JobStatus.ShipMethodTransmitted as TransmitMethod,
     dbo.JobStatus.DateShipTransmitProcessed as DateProcessed,
     dbo.JobStatus.ShipmentProcessedBy as ProcesssedBy,
    dbo.JobStatus.Critical,
    dbo.View_JobsToShipCount.JobsToShip,
    dbo.JobStatus.ShipTransmitStatus as Status,
    dbo.JobStatus.InvoiceStatus,
    dbo.InvoiceLineDetail.Quantity
FROM dbo.View_JobsToShipCount 
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.InvoiceLineDetail 
    ON dbo.View_JobsToShipCount.Name = dbo.InvoiceLineDetail.CustomerAccountName 
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.JobStatus 
    ON dbo.InvoiceLineDetail.JobID = dbo.JobStatus.JobTableId

WHERE (dbo.InvoiceLineDetail.ChargeGroup = 'LENS') and ((dbo.JobStatus.InvoiceStatus = N'IR') OR
  (dbo.JobStatus.ShipTransmitStatus = N'ReadyToShip'))
```

Now I want JobNumber and JobID as UNIQUE values. I am getting same records for both.

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Have scroll bar, no read.  No read, no help...

Comment: **you need to learn to format your code better!** +1 to anyone who wants to look at that messy SQL!!! yuck

Comment: Yeah, this could use a little reformatting love to make answering easier...

Comment: It might also help to reduce this problem to a simpler query.  Can you remove some of these columns & coalesce statements (and maybe even joins) and still reproduce the issue?

Comment: LOL! I guess Joe edited it. Thanks Joe :)

Answer (score 3):

If all the other information is the same, simply add a "DISTINCT" to your query.

NOTE: Table aliases REALLY help with readability....

Comment: ADDED DISTINCT to the query: SELECT  DISTINCT dbo.InvoiceLineDetail.JobNumber. But it is giving me this error: The ntext data type cannot be selected as DISTINCT because it is not comparable.

Comment: Why on earth are you using TEXT data types?  What RDBMS is this?

Comment: I'm going to have to go with JNK on this one.....getting a distinct on a text is just a bad bit of news.  You might need to do an intermediary query to get the unique records, THEN get the text values.